# Building Android OS For Devices

Tags: android, android-source, android-configchanges

I am trying to build Android OS. I've set up my machine and everything is going on fine, but selecting the device configuration is my concern. When I type lunch, I get:

```
1 arm-eng
2 aosp_shamu-userdebug
3 aosp_fugu-userdebug
4 aosp_flounder-userdebug
5 aosp_hammerhead-userdebug
6 aosp_flo-userdebug
7 aosp_deb-userdebug
8 full_manta-userdebug
9 full_mako-userdebug
10 full_grouper-userdebug
11 full_tilapia-userdebug
12 full_maguro-userdebug
13 aosp_toro-userdebug
14 (toroplus)   aosp_toroplus-userdebug
15 aosp_panda-userdebug
16 full_wingray-userdebug
17 full_crespo-userdebug
18 full_crespo4g-userdebug
```

I have a device called Injoo 1s, that's what I want to use to test. How do I choose which configuration. Or, I've to write some codes to fix that. Your response would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: The device you have isn't supported by AOSP. You'll have to obtain the necessary configuration and (probably) proprietary binaries from elsewhere. If the manufacturer doesn't supply this maybe somenoe else has already done this work and published what you need.

Comment: Can you help with something. Let's say if I want to build a custom Android OS for this mobile that's not known. What are the process I've to go through. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If its not supported by AOSP, then your best bet is to see if Cyanogen Mod supports it. Otherwise, the process is long and very difficult. It involves piecing together the device drivers and software required to have the device build. It isn't something that can be concisely described in an SO answer really.

Comment: @AndrewT. If you can tell me where I can find out about it, I want to go through the stress. I've a build Machine to it. A 112GBRam machine that builds for me in 20mins Tops. Please help a brother. Thanks.

Comment: I only know the kinds of things you need at  a high level, I suggest you check out the cyanogen forums if you want to learn how to add device support to aosp

Answer (score 1):

The lunch combos are configured via files called `vendorsetup.sh`. Your device should have such a file under `<android>/device/<your-vendor>/<your-device>` with the following contents:

```
add_lunch_combo <your-device>-eng
add_lunch_combo <your-device>-user
```

Comment: Sorry,are you saying I'll need to configure the vendorsetup.sh or by default it's there. I just need to edit it to fit me?

Comment: Of course, in the Android tree there aren't files for every device in the world. The devices listed by `lunch` are the only supported devices per default. If your device has Android running on it, the sources for it aren't necessarily included in AOSP. Every manufacturer is free to keep their sources closed due to the Apache license. So if there is no folder for your device under `<android>/device`, you have to add it by either creating your own (which is a lot of work) or maybe get it from the manufacturer or some open source project like Cyanogen Mod.

Comment: It's not in Cyanogen, I've checked. Well, I want to go through the stress of building it. Is there a way you can help with that?

Comment: Well, it's not just "building" in that case. You probably have to write source code for that. First of all, you have to add board support for your device in the kernel (which in most cases requires knowledge of the hardware, i.e. schematics, and the assembled CPU). Do you have experience in bringing up the Linux kernel on embedded devices? If not, start with something easier, where the hardware is open, like the Raspberry Pi. The second step would be creating a device folder in the Android tree. This is the easier part. Look at other device folders to see what is required here.

Comment: See This [link](http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/build_new_device.html) is it helpful enough? I've been working on that now

Comment: As I said: First step is bringing up the kernel. Don't start with Android unless you have a kernel running on the device. If you have never done this before, there is a lot to learn. Far too much to be covered here. However, I assume it will be impossible to bring up a kernel without having access to the hardware schematics.

Comment: Calfriedrich how can I go about it. Just tell me all I need to do. I'll do it

Comment: Dude, there are complete books about the Linux kernel and bringing it up on custom boards. This is nothing you can explain within a few lines on Stack Overflow.